# Creating a Job using Django to fetch data from API

Tags: python, django, api, cron

I am doing a project using Django that will consume an external API.

However, in this project I will need to set up the times that django will consume this Third API.
So basically, I will need to creat a job to fetch this data.

Do you guys have any public github or a manual that I can use as an example?

I never did this before and it is so hard to find a tutorial about it or something like that.

Comment: So you need to regularly run a script like `manage.py fetch_api`? Are you asking how to set up a cronjob or a Systemd timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appscheduler is one way to do this. You can set time intervals for when to run the function that fetches/processes data from an external API.

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Nice. I already found lots of tutorials about this appscheduler. Thank you so much for that